Elimination in construction sequences of expressions that contain $A_4$
Assume we have a construction sequence ending in $\varphi$, where $\varphi$ does not contain the symbol $\mathbf{A_4}$. Suppose we delete all the expressions in the sequence that contain $\mathbf{A_4}$. Show that the result is still a legal construction sequence.
What I have tried to do is induction on the new sequence lenght.
Let the new sequence be $\langle\epsilon_1, ... , \epsilon_k \rangle$ with $k \in \mathbb{N}$.
For $i=1$ we have that $\epsilon_1$ is a wff. This is the first expression that didn't contain $\mathbf{A_4}$ in the original sequence, therefore it has to be a sentence symbol, meaning it's a wff. We have a valid sequence.
Assume that for $i \in\{1,2,...,k\}$ we have that the sequence $\langle \epsilon_1, ... , \epsilon_i \rangle$ is a legal construction sequence.
Now let us have $i= k+1$, we have that $\epsilon_{k+1}$ does not depend on $\mathbf{A_4}$, therefore either $\epsilon_{k+1}$ is a new sentence symbol or one of the following things happens:

$\epsilon_{k+1}$ is the negation of one of the $\epsilon$ in $\langle \epsilon_1, ... , \epsilon_k \rangle$.
$\epsilon_{k+1}$ is equal to $\epsilon_i \circ \epsilon_j$ for $i,j < k$, where $\circ \in \{\wedge,\vee ,\rightarrow,\leftrightarrow\}$.

In any case, we get a valid expression that does not depend on $\mathbf{A_4}$ and that follows the rules to have a legal construction sequence.
This is the proof that I've come up with. However, I do believe that the inductive step is quite rough and might be completely wrong. Can you help me, please?
Thanks.
EDIT
$\mathbf{A_4}$ is a sentence symbol.
Define a construction sequence to be a finite sequence $\langle \epsilon_1, ..., \epsilon_n \rangle$ of expressions such that for each $i\leq n$ we have at least one of:

$\epsilon_i$ is a sentence symbol
$\epsilon_i = \urcorner \epsilon_j$ for some $j<i$
$\epsilon_{i}$ is equal to $\epsilon_k \circ \epsilon_j$ for $k,j < i$, where $\circ \in \{\wedge,\vee ,\rightarrow,\leftrightarrow\}$.


This question relies on nonstandard terminology that is not explained in the question. Please define "construction sequence". What is $A_4$?

I'll edit the question and add the definitions.

Looks correct to me, but you should mention that $\epsilon_{k+1}$ cannot be a combination of sentences outside of $\epsilon$ because then it would contain $\mathbf{A}_4$.
